# Can I collect donation information in iOS app and then redirect to safari

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an app in the App store which accepts donations ([link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/musalleen/id1227784727?ls=1&mt=8)). In the "Donate" screen, I used to collect donation information and process the donation right there. The Apple team somehow let it pass the first few times and then rejected it and told me I couldn't process in-app donations (I didn't know when I published it) and would have to redirect to safari to process the donation. I asked them for a one time exception and they gave it to me under the condition that the next release must redirect the donations to safari.

Now, I am building the redirect but I am wondering if I can still collect the donation information (cc info, name, donation amount, category, etc.) in the app and just redirect to safari for the confirmation and pass the collected info as query parameters. This will really be minimal effort and make it easy and still preserve some in-app features I have.

I don't want to build this only to have it rejected again. I want to know if the app store will reject for collecting the donation info in-app and doing the final click (actual processing) in safari. If this way it will get rejected, then I will just remake this whole screen in safari and discard this code.

Here is the donate screen currently for context:

[image: Image of donate screen]

Comment: did you found any solution ?